# Algolia & Vue InstantSearch: Customising widgets with slot

Tags: vue.js, algolia, vue-instant-search

I am trying to modify the output of an **InstantSearch** widget for **Vue**.

In the documentation (https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/hits/vue/#customize-the-ui) it says that using the scope-slot it will override the complete DOM output of the widget:

[image]

But it does not seem to be the case here. This is my code below using slot with a simple `<tr>` and `<td>` elements:

[image]

Instead of rendering a `<tr>` with `<td>` inside of it, I see here:

- A **div** with a class of **ais-Hits**
- A nested **ol** with a class of **ais-Hits-list**
- A nested **li** with a class of **ais-Hits-item**

[image]

The output is this:

[image]

If I go to *inspect element* and I delete the elements I mentioned above (see how **div**, **ol** and **li** are deleted):

[image]

Then the result is correct:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Shouldn't slot override the DOM output and leave the rest to the developer to style?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the [`default`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/hits/vue/#widget-param-default) slots rather than `item`. You'll have full control over the render.

```
<ais-hits>
  <ol slot-scope="{ items }">
    <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.objectID">
      <ais-highlight :hit="item" attribute="name" />
      <p>
        <ais-highlight :hit="item" attribute="description" />
      </p>
    </li>
  </ol>
</ais-hits>
```

Here is an example on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-instantsearch-custom-hits-6hnu1).

---

The `ais-Hits` will always wrap the default slot with a `div` (see [GitHub](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5758) for the explaination). The only alternative to avoid this issue is to [create your own widget](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/widgets/create-your-own-widgets/vue/) with the mixin `createWidgetMixin`:

```
<template>
  <ol v-if="state">
    <li v-for="item in state.hits" :key="item.objectID">
      <ais-highlight :hit="item" attribute="name" />
      <p>
        <ais-highlight :hit="item" attribute="description" />
      </p>
    </li>
  </ol>
</template>

<script>
import { createWidgetMixin } from "vue-instantsearch";
import { connectHits } from "instantsearch.js/es/connectors";

export default {
  mixins: [createWidgetMixin({ connector: connectHits })]
};
</script>
```

Here is an example on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-instantsearch-custom-hits-6hnu1).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I managed to remove the ol and li but <ais-hits> create a div with class="ais-Hits" that breaks the table. Is there a way to avoid this div?

Comment: With the slots you can't get rid of the top level `div`. It's a limitation of Vue, the root element can't be a slot or a template. The only alternative is to create a custom widget with the mixin. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Although @Samuel Vaillant pointed me at the correct path, I believe the code below can help others with the same issue as me (populating HTML tables with Algolia results) without needing to create custom widgets:

```
<template>
  <ais-hits>
    <table slot-scope="{ items }">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="item in items" :key="item.objectID">
          <td>
            <ais-highlight :hit="item" attribute="name" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <ais-highlight :hit="item" attribute="description" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </ais-hits>
</template>
```

Comment: this should be best answer